# Have view centered and fill available height without going offscreen

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've got a situation where I would like a view to be centered in its superview, remain square, but fill as much height as possible without going off the edge, i.e., it should look at the available vertical and horizontal space, choosing the smallest between the 2.

There are 2 other views, one below and one above, that will both be either a button or label. The bottom/top of these views should be attached to the top/bottom of the central view. I can get this to work, to an extent, but I'll explain my issue below, and what I've got so far:

Top label has:

- .Top >= TopLayoutGuide.Bottom
- .Top = TopLayoutGuide.Bottom (*priority 250*)
- .Right = CentralView.Right

Central view has:

- Center X and Y = Superview Center X and Y
- .Height <= Superview.Width * 0.9
- .Width = self.Height
- .Top = TopLabel.Bottom

Bottom button has:

- .Right = CentralView.Right
- .Top = CentralView.Bottom
- .Bottom <= (BottomLayoutGuide.Top - 16)

Running this seems fine, and produces the desired results:

[image: Correct Layout]

However, if I make the view an instance of my custom class and add a UIButton subview, it all goes wrong. In this class I perform:

```
self.topLeftButton = CustomButtonClass()
self.topLeftButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
self.addSubview(self.topLeftButton)

self.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.topLeftButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.topLeftButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.topLeftButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.topLeftButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.topLeftButton, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        ])
```

Using this code the view collapses down to the following:

[image: Incorrect Layout]

I can't figure out why this is. I've made a few small tweaks here and there, but not managed to get it to work as desired. If I add the same button in IB the view wants to collapse again, and it's as if the button will not grow in height.

Comment: I know, let's all attach gigantic images to our questions so that they're really hard to read! :)

Comment: I also find this annoying, but there's no way to resize it within the editor, so I need to resize them and re-upload them

Comment: Content hugging settings?

Comment: Button and central view are 250 Content Hugging, label is 251. Admittedly, it's something I struggle with and have looked up but could not figure out the correct values to have it work as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real life I wouldn't subclass UIButton, but have done in my answer, as that is what the question indicated. UIButton works best through composition. So maybe better to create a UIButton, then modify its properties.

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var view = CustomView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        var label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Label"

        var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
        button.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)

        view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        self.view.addSubview(view)
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        // The width should be as big as possible...
        var maxWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view.superview, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        // ... but not at the expense of other constraints
        maxWidthConstraint.priority = 1

        self.view.addConstraints([
                // Max width, if possible
                maxWidthConstraint,
                // Width and height can't be bigger than the container
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: view.superview, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: view.superview, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                // Width and height are equal
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                // View is centered
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view.superview, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view.superview, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        ])

        // Label above view
        self.view.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: label.superview, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        ])

        // Button below view
        self.view.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: button.superview, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        ])

    }
}


class CustomView: UIView {

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override init() {

        super.init()
        var button = CustomButton()
        button.setTitle("Custom Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        self.addSubview(button)

        // Custom button in the top left
        self.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),

        ])
    }
}


class CustomButton: UIButton {

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost there, but the issue that the height cannot be bigger than its superview's height, plus the heights of the label and button. This solution only seems to ensure that it's small than the total height of the superview. I've added the `maxWidthConstraint`, so that might help somewhere along the way!

Comment: I've updated my answer to constrain the top of the label and the bottom of the button to be within the screen, and to be flush with the view.

Comment: After reviewing your first question I went back and changed the Greater Than or Equal constraints on the top of the label from the original question to have 750 priority. I then setup the button at the bottom to have a similar setup and got it working. I think I modified a couple of other things thanks to your answer, so I'll mark it as accepted and continue on :)